# Resuming a dead app from background is making it behave weirdly

Tags: android, android-fragments, transactionmanager

I am building an application which has the following structure.

```
MainActivity -> Fragment1
             -> Fragment2 -> Fragment3
```

Here Fragment1 is hosted on MainActivity in FrameLayout. when user click any option on Fragment1, I am switching to Fragment2 which hosts Fragment3 on ViewPager.

Problem is, if user moves to android home without closing the app, and in a duration of time the app is killed by Android, and user tries to resume the app from recent app list, Fragment3 is displaying the blank screen.

here is the method which I am using for Fragment transaction

```
public void requestChangeFragment(Fragment newFragment,String tag,Fragment oldFragment, int anim_in, int anim_out){
        if(isStopped()){
            return;
        }
        mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(anim_in,anim_out,anim_in,anim_out);
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_frame_layout, newFragment, tag);
        Log.i("FragMngr","Animations set in "+anim_in+" out "+anim_out);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(tag);
        int count = mFragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount();
        String log="";
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager.BackStackEntry backStackEntry = mFragmentManager.getBackStackEntryAt(i);
            log += "count "+i+" name "+backStackEntry.getName()+"\n";
        }
        Log.d("FragMngr","BackStack trace after adding is\n "+log);
        if(oldFragment!=null) {
            if(oldFragment.isResumed()) {
                oldFragment.onPause();
            }
        }
        topFragment = newFragment;
    }
```

`requestChangeFragment()` is called from running fragments with the help of `interface` implemented in `MainActivity`.

Comment: Can you post some more code plz. Like onResume and onPause methods

Comment: There is basically nothing in those Methods except the logs. It is crashing even when I am trying to use Crashlytics in these fragments. (Error is, Crashlytics is not initialized) if I am trying to initialize the Crashlytics, Its showing context cannot be null.

Comment: You probably aren't managing the lifecycle really well. Here is a good tutorial if you wnat to read into it https://www.raywenderlich.com/117838/introduction-to-android-fragments-tutorial

Comment: I am handling the life cycle to the extent possible, but issue arises when user go to android home without closing the app and the app process is killed by Android garbage collector.

Comment: You should never ever call `Activity`'s or `Fragment`'s lifecycle callbacks (`onPause()`, etc). System will handle it on its own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research I identified the problem to be the saved instances which stores the current state of the fragment whenever android garbage collector kills the app when app is not in use. So when I tried to resume the dead app, it moves the fragment that was selected before pausing the app. But the fragment do not have any data which it must have received from the it Main class.

Solution : Clear the saved instances in your MainActivity in onCreate method. Or if you are storing any values in your saved instance state, then perform the operation related to the saved Instance State, clear the value and then call `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)`